Higher or lower?
Consider the following game - I draw a number from $[0, 1]$ uniformly, and show it to you. I tell you I am going to draw another $1000$ numbers in sequence, independently and uniformly. Your task is to guess, before any of the $1000$ numbers have been drawn, whether each number will be higher or lower than the previously drawn one in the sequence.
Thus your answer is in the form of a list of $1000$ guesses, all written down in advance, only having seen the first drawn number. At the end of the game, you win a dollar for every correct guess and lose one for every wrong guess.
How do you play this game? Is it possible to ensure a positive return with overwhelming probability? If not, how does one ensure a good chance of not losing too much? For a more precise statement,
Question: Under a strategy that optimises the probability of the stated goal, what is the probability of

A positive return?
A non-negative return?

Some elaboration: The main subtlety is that the list of $1000$ guesses has to be given in advance! So an example game looks like this:

Draw card, it is a $0.7$.

Okay, I guess $LHLHLHHLHL \dots$

$1000$ cards are drawn and compared against your guesses.

???

Payoff!



Do you mean I know the whole process, including that all the numbers come from $[0,1]$ iid? Or is some of the information hidden from me?

@JukkaKohonen You know what the process will be, but at the time of making the guesses the only actual information you have is the first number.

Do I want to maximize by expected value or maximize the probability of positive return? It would be helpful if you made your questions a bit more precise.

@mathworker21 It is sort of open ended by design, but for a precise statement, you could ask first to maximise the probability of positive return, and then the expected value as two seperate questions.

The probability of a strictly positive return is less than $1/2$ whatever your strategy. Let the 1000 unseen numbers be $X_1, \dots, X_{1000}$. If you replace each $X_i$ by $\tilde{X_i}:=1-X_i$, then the correctness of each of the 999 last guesses is flipped. So the distribution of the number of correct guesses among those 999 is symmetric around 999/2. In particular, under any strategy its probability of strictly exceeding 499 is exactly $1/2$. From this you get that the probability of strictly exceeding 500 correct guesses out of 1000 must be less than $1/2$.

@NateRiver I think Mathoverflow is for one precise question. For the expected value, you could use linearity of expectation: for the first guess, you make the obvious guess; for all the others, your probability of being correct is $50%$.

@JamesMartin Oh, interesting find. Then I guess the question is - how high can you get the probability of a non negative return to be with an optimal strategy?

@NateRiver, just an aside, an interesting counterpart question is when you observe each number $X_n$ in the sequence before deciding whether the next number $X_{n+1}$ is higher or lower (than $X_{n}$).

Since the original question asked for the strategy that maximizes the probability of having a positive return, the other answer is incorrect.
Let $\{X_i\}_{i=0,\dots,n}$ with $X_i$ iid, $X_0 \sim \text{unif}(0,1)$, and we are given the value of $X_0$. Let $\{u_i\}_{i=0,\dots,n-1}$ be the predictions made from our strategy. The choice of $u_i$ for $i \geq 1$ does matter as illustrated by the following example.
Consider the extreme example where $n=2$ and fix the initial value as $X_0=0.7$. To have a positive return we need both our predictions to be correct. Compare the probability of a positive return for guessing LL (lower, lower) and LH (lower, higher):
By integrating over the desired region, we find for strategy LL:
$$P(\text{Strategy LL payout}>0)=P(X_1<0.7 \text{ and } X_2<X_1)=\int_0^{0.7} \int_0^{x_1} 1\, dx_2\,dx_1=0.245,$$
and for strategy LH:
$$P(\text{Strategy LH payout}>0)=P(X_1<0.7 \text{ and } X_2>X_1)=\int_0^{0.7} \int_{x_1}^1 1\, dx_2\,dx_1=0.455.$$
Clearly, the choice of strategy affects the probability of a positive return. While the difference between strategies diminishes as $n$ increases, for small $n$, the difference can be substantial.
Manually calculating best strategy for $n=3$
For $n=3$ we have to get a positive return we need at least two of our guesses to be correct. WLOG let the initial value be $x_0>0.5$. We can manually compute the probability for the 4 different strategies (fixing the initial guess as L). Splitting it up into disjoint events and integrating over the desired region gives us:
$$P(\text{Strategy LLL payout}>0)=P(X_1<x_0 \text{ and } X_2<X_1)+P(X_1<x_0 \text { and } X_2>X_1 \text{ and } X_3<X_2) + P(X_1>x_0 \text{ and } X_2<X_1 \text{ and } X_3<X_2)=\int_0^{x_0} \int_0^{x_1} 1\, dx_2\,dx_1 + \int_0^{x_0} \int_{x_1}^1\int_0^{x_2} 1\, dx_3\,dx_2\,dx_1+\int_{x_0}^1 \int_0^{x_1}\int_0^{x_2} 1\, dx_3\,dx_2\,dx_1 = \\ \frac{x_0^2}{2}-\frac{1}{6}x_0(x_0^2-3)+\frac{1}{6}(1-x_0^3).$$
Similarly, for the rest, we get:
\begin{align*}
P(\text{Strategy LLH payout}>0)&=\frac{x_0^2}{2}+\frac{1}{6}x_0(x_0^2-3x_0+3)+\frac{1}{6}(x_0^3-3x_0^2+2) \\
P(\text{Strategy LHH payout}>0)&=-\frac{1}{2}(x_0-2)x_0-\frac{1}{6}(x_0-3)x_0^2-\frac{1}{6}(x_0-1)^3 \\
P(\text{Strategy LHL payout}>0)&=-\frac{1}{2}(x_0-2)x_0+\frac{x_0^3}{6}+\frac{1}{6}(x_0^3-3x_0+2)
\end{align*}
Note, that $P(\text{Strategy LLL payout}>0)=P(\text{Strategy LHH payout}>0)$ and $P(\text{Strategy LLH payout}>0)=P(\text{Strategy LHL payout}>0)$, and the strategy LLL/LHH strictly dominates the strategy LLH/LHL for all $x_0 \in (0.5, 1)$.
In theory, we could continue like this (there might be a quick argument that only guessing L is the (not unique) best strategy for $n$ being odd), but we will do some simulations instead.
Simulate for small $n$ to find a good strategy
Simulating the game with initial value $X_0=0.7$ and repeating $10^5$ times for the $2^{n-1}$ different strategies (fixing initial guess as L) gives us the difference between the best and worst performing strategy for $n=2,\dots,7$.



n
Best strategy (proportion of positive returns)
Worst strategy (proportion of positive returns)




2
LH (0.45)
LL (0.24)


3
LLL (0.65)
LLH (0.55)


4
LHLL (0.44)
LLLL (0.31)


5
LHHHH (0.62)
LHLHH (0.54)


6
LHLHLH (0.43)
LLLLLL (0.34)


7
LLLLLLL (0.60)
LLHLHLH (0.55)



Observations from simulations

For odd $n$, betting only L (i.e., always guessing that the next value is lower) seems to be one of the best strategies.

For even $n$, the strategy of alternating between L and H (starting with L) tends to perform well.

The strategy of always guessing L tends to be one of the worst performing strategies for even $n$.


Thus, based on these simulations and some manual calculations, a reasonable educated guess for an optimal strategy is as follows:

If $n$ is odd, always guess L if the initial value $X_0 > 0.5$; otherwise, always guess H.

If $n$ is even, alternate guesses (L, H, L, H, etc.) starting with L if $X_0 > 0.5$; otherwise, start with H.


Checking the performance of our strategy
Odd $n$
We simulate the game for odd values of $n$ using the "always guess L" strategy and compare it with a baseline where guesses are made randomly after the initial guess. For each $n$, we simulate $10^6$ repetitions for each strategy, with the initial value fixed at $X_0 = 0.7$. The plot below shows the proportion of positive returns for both strategies:
$n$" />
Even $n$
Similarly, we simulate the game for even values of $n$ using the alternating strategy (L, H, L, H, ...) and compare it with random guessing. Again, we for each $n$ simulate $10^6$ repetitions for each strategy, with the initial value fixed at $X_0 = 0.7$.
$n$" />
Results
From the simulations, we observe that our educated guess for an optimal strategy does seem to significantly outperform random guessing for both $n$ being even and odd.
Non-negative returns
I only focused on having a positive return. For non-negative return, a quick simulation shows that only betting L for $X_0>0.5$ seems to maximize the probability (both for $n$ being even and odd). But, all the arguments would be the same, so it is omitted.
Code
The R code for my simulation for odd $n$ is given below (the other simulations are just small modifications of this):
# 0 is lower 1 is higher
simulate_game <- function(n, initial_value, strategy) {
  draws <- runif(n)
  draws <- c(initial_value, draws)

  # Strategy 1: Always guess lower if initial > 0.5, else always guess higher
  if (strategy == 1) {
    if (initial_value > 0.5) {
      guesses <- rep(0, n)
    } else {
      guesses <- rep(1, n)
    }
  }

  # Strategy 2: Guess randomly after initial guess
  if (strategy == 2) {
    if (initial_value > 0.5) {
      guesses <- c(0, sample(0:1, n-1, replace = TRUE))
    } else {
      guesses <- c(1, sample(0:1, n-1, replace = TRUE))
    }
  }

  # Calculate the number of correct guesses
  correct_guesses <- sum((draws[2:(n + 1)] > draws[1:n]) == guesses)
  wrong_guesses <- n - correct_guesses

  # Winnings: Net positive if correct guesses exceed wrong guesses
  winnings <- correct_guesses - wrong_guesses

  return(winnings > 0)  # Return TRUE if the strategy made money
}

compare_strategies <- function(n, k, initial_value = 0.7) {
  # Initialize counters for successful simulations
  strategy1_successes <- 0
  strategy2_successes <- 0

  for (i in 1:k) {
    # Simulate strategy 1
    if (simulate_game(n, initial_value, strategy = 1)) {
      strategy1_successes <- strategy1_successes + 1
    }

    # Simulate strategy 2
    if (simulate_game(n, initial_value, strategy = 2)) {
      strategy2_successes <- strategy2_successes + 1
    }
  }

  # Calculate proportions of times each strategy made money
  strategy1_proportion <- strategy1_successes / k
  strategy2_proportion <- strategy2_successes / k

  return(list(strategy1_proportion = strategy1_proportion,
              strategy2_proportion = strategy2_proportion))
}

n_values <- 1+seq(50, 1000, by = 50)
k <- 10^6  
set.seed(1405)

results_odd <- pblapply(n_values, function(n) compare_strategies(n, k))


Oh wow nice, you even found the optimal strategies for small $n$ for illustration. This is the answer I expected at first.

Let $\mathcal W^*$ be the set of all words (including the empty word $E$) over the alphabet $\{L,H\}$. For
each $w\in \mathcal W^*$ let $|w|$ be length of the word $w$. For each $w\in \mathcal W^*$, nonnegative integer $n$, and $x\in [0,1]$ let $P(w,n,x)$ be the probability to have exactly $n$ correct guesses in the sequence $w$, provided the number $x$ is shown. Then $P(E,0,x)=1$ and if $n>|w|$ then $P(w,n,x)=0$. Moreover, we suppose that for each $w\in\mathcal W^*$, $n\in\mathbb N$, and $x\in [0,1]$ we have
$$P(Lw,0,x)=\int_x^1 P(w,0,t)dt,$$
$$P(Lw,n,x)=\int_0^x P(w,n-1,t)dt+\int_x^1 P(w,n,t)dt,$$
$$P(Hw,0,x)=\int_0^x P(w,0,t)dt.$$
and
$$P(Hw,n,x)=\int_0^x P(w,n,t)dt+\int_x^1 P(w,n-1,t)dt.$$
It suggests that $$P(w,n,x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a(w,n,i) x^i,$$
such that $a(w,n,i)=0$ for each $W\in\mathcal W^*$, nonnegative integer $n$, and $i\in \mathbb N$ with $i>|w|$. Moreover, $a(E,0,0)=1$ and $a(E,n,i)=0$ for each nonnegative integers $i,n$ with $i+n>0$. Also for each $w\in\mathcal W^*$ and $n, i\in\mathbb N$ we have
$$a(Lw,0,0)=\sum_{i=0}^{|w|} \frac{a(w,0,i)}{i+1}, a(Lw,0,i)=-\frac{a(w,0,i-1)}{i}, $$
$$a(Hw,0,0)=0,\mbox{ and } a(Hw,0,i)=\frac{a(w,0,i-1)}{i},$$
$$a(Lw,n,i)=\frac{a(w,n-1,i-1)-a(w,n,i-1)}{i},$$ $$a(Lw,n,0)=\sum_{i=0}^{|w|} \frac{a(w,n,i)}{i+1},$$
$$a(Hw,n,i)=\frac{a(w,n,i-1)-a(w,n-1,i-1)}{i},$$ and $$a(Hw,n,0)=\sum_{i=0}^{|w|} \frac{a(w,n-1,i)}{i+1}.$$
The above recursive formulae allow to calculate for short $w$ the polynomials $P(w,n,x)$ and the polynomial $P_+(w,x)=\sum_{2n>|w|} P(w,n,x)$. I wrote a program for that, which made the calculations
for small odd $|w|$ and even $|w|\le 14$.
They suggest that for each length $\ell\ne 8$ there exists a word $w(\ell)\in\mathcal W^*$ of length $\ell$ such that for each word $w\in\mathcal W^*$ with $|w|=\ell$ and each $x\in [1/2,1]$ we have $P_+(w(\ell),x)\ge P_+(w,x)$.
For instance, see below the graphs with $|w|=5$ drawn inside the unit square, where the graph(s) corresponding to $w(\ell)$ are red and the other graphs are black.

As far as I see, if $\ell$ is odd then $w(\ell)$ is $L^\ell$ or $LH^{\ell-1}$, and if $\ell$ is even then $w(\ell)$ is $(LH)^{\ell/2}$, if $\ell\ne 4,8$, and $LHLL$, if $\ell=4$; for $\ell=8$, the situation is more refined. Namely, for most $x\in [1/2,1]$ and $w\in\mathcal W^*$ with $|w|=8$ we have $P_+(LHLHLLHL,x)\ge P_+(w,x)$, but for $x\in (\approx 0.5000, \approx 0.5045)$, $P_+((LH)^4,x)$ is a bit bigger than $P_+(LHLHLLHL,x)$.
This confirms the best strategies listed in the table from the other answer and suggests that the other answer is correct. Note that although at the beginning of that answer is stated that "the other answer is incorrect" this does not lead to a paradox, because there is meant the earlier answer, which is deleted now. :-)
I wrote an other program to calculate $P_+((LH)^{\ell/2},x)$. For technical reasons (I am an old school guy and still writing in Pascal under DOSBox :-) ), I picked $\ell=60$. We have
$$P_+((LH)^{30},x)\approx 0.4203+0.0808x-0.0016x^2+0.0006x^3+\dots.$$
I do not provide the other coefficients $a_i$ of $P_+((LH)^{30},x)$ because, as far as I see, their absolute values decay very quickly, and generally $|a_i|$ is even smaller than $10^{-i}$.
